# Dust.js Promise Array

Tags: javascript, dust.js

I have an issue with promises that resolve an array in Dust.js

Say I have a Dust.js function like so (this will be doing something else later on but for sake of a simple example), which resolves an array:

```
var doSomethingAsync = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // do a thing, possibly async, then…
  setTimeout(function(){

        var items = [{
            name: 'One',
        }, {
            name: 'Two',
        }, {
            name: 'Three',
        }];

        resolve(items);
    }, 5000);
});

res.stream('admin/index', {
    "async": doSomethingAsync
});
```

and my template is like this:

```
{#async}
    {name}
{/async}
```

It doesn't seem to print out what you would expect. Using contextDump helper it prints this:

```
[ { "name": "One" }, { "name": "Two" }, { "name": "Three" } ]
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong, whether this is intended behaviour or whether it is a bug?

Comment: Dust 2.7.2 is out with the fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct. Currently the entire Array gets pushed onto the context, so you then have to iterate over your context:

```
{#async}
    {#.}
        {name}
    {/.}
{/async}
```

But this is [fixed in Dust 2.7.2](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/pull/676).

Using that version, you can iterate over the returned Array just as you'd expect.

```
{#async}
    {name}
{/async}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you have to loop through itself...

```
{#async}
    {#.}
        {name}
    {/.}
{/async}
```

Comment: This seems like a bug; I opened an issue for you on our issue tracker: https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs/issues/674

Comment: This will be fixed in 2.7.2